# Java. How to redefine onCompletion method of a MediaPlayer instance

Tags: java, android, interface, android-mediaplayer, abstract-class

I have a `MediaPlayer` instance `mPlayer`.

When the play of `mPlayer` has completed, I want to do some action. I've seen that this is done by the method `onCompletion` of the interface [OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html).

How can I redefine this method for my `mPlayer` instance?

Edit:

I have created my API AudioPlayer.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioPlayer {

    public MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    public AudioPlayer(String source, boolean loop) {
        configurePlayer(source, loop);
    }

    private void configurePlayer(String source, boolean loop) {
        try {
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(source);
            mPlayer.setLooping(loop);
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    public void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Now I have various AudioPlayers. But I only want one play at a time. Thus, I have implemented mutual exclusion (not exactly, but it is enough for my app).

```
boolean token = true;

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (token) {
        token = false;
        mPlayer.startPlaying();
    }
}
```

Now I want that when the play ends, the token is returned. Something like

```
onCompletion() {
    token = true;
}
```

Comment: What have you done until now, show us your `MediaPlayer` and what action you need on `OnCompletionListener`.

Comment: @Stanojkovic Done! Question edited

Comment: mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      mPlayer.release();
                                                token = true;
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do the following:

1. Modify your class declaration to implement `OnCompletionListener`;
2. Implement listener's `onCompletion()` method;
3. Set current class as `mPlayer`'s `OnCompletionListener`.

Here is modified code snippet:

```
public class AudioPlayer implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener { // 1

    public MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    public AudioPlayer(String source, boolean loop) {
        configurePlayer(source, loop);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); // 3
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { // 2
        token = true;
    }

    /* the other class implementation */
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Ok! And I dont want all instances of AudioPlayer to override `onCompletion`. Thus, a third boolean parameter `override` to AudioPlayer constructor would be nice, and then `if (override)`, do `setOnCompletionListener`

Comment: Yeap, as an option. Of course, you can use along with your `if(override)` clause in the constructor `mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                token = true;
            }
        });`
instead of specifying `OnCompletionListener` in class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to extend MediaPlayer class and then override method witch u want to redefine using super()

Comment: I don't want all the instances of AudioPlayer to override the method.